# Azure AD B2C LinkedIn profile picture

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm currently using Azure AD B2C with LinkedIn integration to log into my application. The login process is working and i get back several claims regarding the user such as name and e-mail address.

I want to get the LinkedIn profile picture in order to have a default profile picture in my app. I try to use custom policies but I can't get them to work. I tried editing the **TrustFrameworkBase.xml** and **TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml** but nothing came out of it yet.
I added linkedIn as a claimprovider in my TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml

```
 <ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>linkedin.com</Domain>
  <DisplayName>LinkedIn</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LinkedIn-OAUTH">
      <DisplayName>LinkedIn</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ProviderName">linkedin</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization</Item>
        <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,headline, picture-url)</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointAccessTokenName">oauth2_access_token</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointFormatName">format</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointFormat">json</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">r_emailaddress r_basicprofile</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id"><CLIENT ID OF LINKEDIN APP></Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_LinkedInSecret" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="id" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="firstName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="lastName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="emailAddress" />
        <!--<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" PartnerClaimType="headline" />-->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="linkedin.com" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Picture" PartnerClaimType="pictureUrl" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

I Also added this Claimtype in my TrustFrameworkBase.xml

```
  <ClaimType Id="extension_Picture">
    <DisplayName>Picture</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
      <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="picture" />
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="picture" />
      <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/extension_Picture" />
    </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
    <UserHelpText>Your picture.</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
  </ClaimType>
```

Does someone know how to properly implement the claims on Azure so that i can get a profile picture from linkedIn?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and **what has been done so far to solve it**.
All I want to say, this is fairly complex to achieve, when at all. Once ppl used the old good [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/) - you can fairly easy build a default profile picture based on gravatar in hint your users to use it.

Comment: Thanks you for your comment. I tried extending my answer so that more information is provided and I hope you might be able to help me further.

Comment: have you inspected the raw LinkedIn token? Does the picture url claim come as `pictureUrl` or `picture-url`? According to the [docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile) it is `picture-url` and you have configured it `PartnerClaimType="pictureUrl"`. And in your claims schema definition as `picture`. Also, by the way, avoid editing too much the base, you can add the claims types in your `Extention` policy.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed  the pictureUrl to picture-url but the sign in policy still does not return a LinkedIn picture url. Do you have an idea how to properly debug the custom policies? I have a lot of trouble finding documentation for Azure ad b2c policies regarding linkedIn as idp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I have retrieved the **picture-url** field for the LinkedIn user and then issued a **picture** claim in the ID token.

1: Complete [the Azure Active Directory B2C: Get started with custom policies steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom) with one of the social account policies such as [the SocialAndLocalAccounts one](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts).

2: Declare a **picture** claim in [the extensions file](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml):

```xml
<ClaimType Id="picture">
  <DisplayName>Picture</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
    <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="picture" />
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="picture" />
  </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
</ClaimType>
```

3: Add both the **picture-url** field to the **ClaimsEndpoint** metadata item and the **picture** output claim to the **LinkedIn-OAUTH** technical profile in [the extensions file](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml):

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>linkedin.com</Domain>
  <DisplayName>LinkedIn</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LinkedIn-OAUTH">
      <DisplayName>LinkedIn</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ProviderName">linkedin</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization</Item>
        <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,formatted-name,email-address,picture-url)</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointAccessTokenName">oauth2_access_token</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointFormatName">format</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointFormat">json</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">r_emailaddress r_basicprofile</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">Your LinkedIn application client ID</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_LinkedInSecret" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="id" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="formattedName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="emailAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="linkedin.com" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="picture" PartnerClaimType="pictureUrl" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

4: Issue the **picture** claim in [the sign-up or sign-in relying party file](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts/SignUpOrSignin.xml):

```xml
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
  <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
    <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="picture" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
  </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```

The ID token is then issued with a **picture** claim such as:

```
"picture": "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5603AQGuMHK965UNqA/profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100/0?e=1537401600&v=beta&t=e0yFYCn0QTn-dY7FJH_YOjIUY8cumr1llEnAMUVq38g"
```